# How to iterate through dynamic arrays in nested loops

Tags: javascript

I have nested for loops that add property values to an object.
The array that each lower loop is iterating through is being filtered by a function that takes as an argument the array value from the loop above it, but I'm running into issues because my filtering function is too slow to keep up with my loops.

```js
// properties/number of properties of LISTS vary
LISTS = {
    A: [{name:"Ben",id:"123"},{name:"Jerry",id:"456"}],
    B: [{name:"Jerry",id:"456"},{name:"Susan",id:"891"}],
    C: [{name:"Dave",id:"789"},{name:"Buster",id:"321"}],
    D: [{name:"Buster",id:"321"},{name:"James",id:"235"}]
}
LISTKEYS = Object.keys(LISTS);
OBJCONTAINER = [];

function mainFunction() {
    var myObj = {};
    var filteredLists = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < LISTS[LISTKEYS[0]].length; i++) {
        myObj[LISTKEYS[0]] = LISTS[LISTKEYS[0]][i];                                                                             
        if (LISTKEYS.length > 1) {
            filteredLists = filterList(myObj,1);
            for (var j = 0; j < filteredLists.length; j++) {
                myObj[LISTKEYS[1]] = filteredLists[j];                                                                                      
                OBJCONTAINER.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj)));
            }
        } else {
            OBJCONTAINER.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj)));
        }                                           
    }
}


function filterList(myObj,index) {
    var filteredLists = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < LISTS[LISTKEYS[index]].length; i++) {
        if (!objPropToArray(myObj,"id").slice(0,index).includes(LISTS[LISTKEYS[index]][i].id)) {
            filteredLists.push(LISTS[LISTKEYS[index]][i]);
        }
    }
    return filteredLists;           
}

function objPropToArray(obj,prop) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj[key][prop] != undefined) {
            arr.push(obj[key][prop]);
        }
    }
    return arr;     
}

mainFunction();
```

Could a callback or promise help me here?
I keep getting stuck because I'm not trying to delay the call of another function, but the start of the next loop.

I've updated my code. The result I'm looking for is for OBJCONTAINER to contain all possible combinations of name/id objects in A and B spots, but the same name/id object cannot appear in both the A and B spot of any one object. The code currently pushes only 3 objects into OBJCONTAINER.

Comment: Just write what you have and what you want get.

Comment: could you provide a sample of the desired output ?

Comment: Yes async await can help you, but you need to provide more code

Comment: it depends on the `functionToFilterMyArr` function and what it is supposed to do, does it get values from a DB ?